# Releasing 2 times?

Tags: iphone, release-management

I am confused with releasing the object that I first alloc/initialized and then copied. As far as I understood the memory management manual I should release the object 2 times because by allocating it and then later copying it I should have retain value of 2? 
So first release would lower it to one and second to 0?
I get message sent to dealloc object if I release it twice. If I do it once there are no problems in application, but there is one in my understanding of Objetive C  mem. management :)))

The only explanation that I can think of is when you release an object from soecific context it will release it instantly no matter the value of retain count ?

In the snippet bellow xmlElement is the confusing one....

```
// LSnippet of code for TouchXML
for (CXMLElement *resultElement in resultNodes) {

    NSMutableDictionary *xmlElement = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    // Create a counter variable as type "int"
    int counter;

    // Loop through the children of the current  node
    for(counter = 0; counter < [resultElement childCount]; counter++) {

        // Add each field to the blogItem Dictionary with the node name as key and node value as the value
        [xmlElement setObject:[[resultElement childAtIndex:counter] stringValue] forKey:[[resultElement childAtIndex:counter] name]];
    }

    // Add the blogItem to the global blogEntries Array so that the view can access it.


    [tempReturnedElements addObject:[xmlElement copy]];
    [xmlElement release];    
    //[xmlElement release]; but NOT!


}
```

UPDATE: whole method code:

```
+(void) runXPath:(NSString *)xPathExpression{

CXMLDocument *rssParser = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:xmlStringContent options:0 error:nil] autorelease];

// Create a new Array object to be used with the looping of the results from the rssParser
NSArray *resultNodes = NULL;


// Set the resultNodes Array to contain an object for every instance of an  node in our RSS feed
resultNodes = [rssParser nodesForXPath:xPathExpression error:nil];

NSMutableArray *tempReturnedElements = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

// Loop through the resultNodes to access each items actual data
for (CXMLElement *resultElement in resultNodes) {

    // Create a temporary MutableDictionary to store the items fields in, which will eventually end up in blogEntries
    NSMutableDictionary *xmlElement = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    // Create a counter variable as type "int"
    int counter;

    // Loop through the children of the current  node
    for(counter = 0; counter < [resultElement childCount]; counter++) {

        // Add each field to the blogItem Dictionary with the node name as key and node value as the value
        [xmlElement setObject:[[resultElement childAtIndex:counter] stringValue] forKey:[[resultElement childAtIndex:counter] name]];
    }

    // Add the blogItem to the global blogEntries Array so that the view can access it.


    [tempReturnedElements addObject:[xmlElement copy]];
//***** Crushes if I use:
//***** [tempReturnedElements addObject:[[xmlElement copy] autorelease]];
    [xmlElement release];



}


[lotojuegosAppDelegate setMyReturnedXmlElements:[tempReturnedElements copy]];

[tempReturnedElements release];
```

}

Thanks in advance,
Luka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is pretty simple: for each `alloc/init`, `copy` or `retain` you must call exactly one `release` or `autorelease` when you want to give up the ownership. You've only called one `alloc/init`, so you may only call `release` once.

This line:

```
[tempReturnedElements addObject:[xmlElement copy]];
```

should be written as:

```
[tempReturnedElements addObject:[[xmlElement copy] autorelease]];
```

The reason is: `copy` gives you a new object. The retain count/ownership of the object pointed to by `xmlElement` is unchanged, but the new object now belongs to you. You're responsible for releasing it now. See the first paragraph in this answer: you called copy, you need to call release on the resulting object.

Comment: Ok, I had no idea that copying is not changing the retain count of original object. I mean I read it
but I forgot this. Thanks for this one….
If I got it all right…
Copy creates duplicate of xmlElement and retain of both objects is 1. 
Since the copied object is not assigned to any other object (like in KennyTM's answer) I can't call [xmlElement release]
twice because it doesn't know which xmlElement of the two (alloc or copied) I'm releasing?
That is why you are using autorelease?

Comment: Almost correct: the `xmlElement` variable is still pointing to the original object so the system does "know" which object you're talking to, and as you've correctly said its retain count is 1. So only one `release` needed. And now we need to take care of the copy: You can either catch the pointer to the copy in a variable like @KennyTM suggested and call `release` on that variable later or directly call `autorelease` on the copy (its return value is the object it was called on). With `autorelease` you basically say: *Hey autorelease pool, you're the owner now, release it later, kthxbye.*

Comment: Thank you a lot for clarification :) Few question that arose... 
1. If dictionary implementations keep retain to everything added why do we send it copied element and not the original? The original object shouldn't be deleted until dictionary releases its retain? All code using dictionaries I saw so far use this technique addObject:[object copy]. 
SHouldn't addObject:object be sufficient?
2. Does the object get inserted into dictionary instantly after calling the addObject method or at the end of the current context? 
Thnx

Comment: The reason why often the values are copied when adding to a dictionary and an array is when the value might in fact be mutable, like an NSString: image you got passed an NSMutableString, and sometime later that string is modified. Your array/dictionary now doesn't look like what you've expected. If the object is not to be expected to have a mutable variant or it wouldn't matter then you don't need to copy. And yes, the object is retained/inserted immediately on addObject, you can safely release your object immediately afterwards.

Comment: Great and simple explanation... Thanks :)

Comment: Something is wrong....
I just changed:
    **[tempReturnedElements addObject:[xmlElement copy]];**
into
**[tempReturnedElements addObject:[[xmlElement copy] autorelease];**
and app crashes with: _[CFDictionary objectForKey:]: message sent to deallocated instance_
I think it makes no difference but I'll point out anyway that this code is in static method context (in AppDelegate)
I just thought I got it all right :DDD

Comment: This looks like you've set the `[` and `]` wrong and autoreleased the *dictionary*. Should be: `[tempReturnedElements addObject:[[xmlElement copy] autorelease]];`

Comment: I am so sorry but in my previous comment I made a typo: I am using: [tempReturnedElements addObject:[[xmlElement copy] autorelease]]; when it crushes... I updated the code so that you can see the whole method...

Answer (score 3):

In `[xmlElement copy]`, only the returned object (i.e. the copy) needs to be released. The receiver (`xmlElement`)'s ownership (retain count) is not changed.

So the correct way should be

```
    NSDictionary* xmlElemCopy = [xmlElement copy];
    [tempReturnedElements addObject:xmlElemCopy];
    [xmlElemCopy release];
    [xmlElement release];
```